# How to jump to a specific frame with actionscript 3 avoiding others movieclips?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip, timeline

I have a problem regarding flash, actionscript3 and movieclips.

I have 2 videos(inserted as movieclips, each one in different frames 100 and 102). 
I want to gotoAndPlay the one on frame 102, but the other in frame 100 always starts at the same time.
How do I play just the specific movieclip of frame 102?

P.S. If I order to reproduce the movieclip on 100, it starts as it should.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just have videos on stage. You should make a MovieClip containing each of these videos and add

```
stop();
```

to their first frames. Add instance names to the MovieClips and you'll be able to control them separately

```
mc1.gotoAndPlay(100);
mc2.gotoAndPlay(200);
```

Comment: thanks man. They were on movieClips, nevertheless I wasn't using the function call directly from the movieClip